# How to track the ratings In-App Message PushWoosh

Tags: javascript, android, events, tracking, pushwoosh

i follow in this http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/rate-my-app-in-app-message but i don't know how to track the ratings. Please tell me how to handle it. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Pushwoosh "Rate My App" In-App Message posts event with the name "Rate My App" when user makes the rating. The attribute "rating" for the event contains the rating itself.

You'll need to create this event for your app (as it is only created by default for the "Pushwoosh Demo App") with the "rating" attribute of "Integer" type.

You can read more here (with screenshots):
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/rate-my-app-in-app-message#7-but-wait-theres-more-lets-track-the-ratings

Comment: I created new event same as instruction but when i track the ratings, it have nothing to show in statistics.

Comment: Could you contact Pushwoosh support and mention your username so the team could check the set up?